# SQL Selecting from Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with contract ids that have multiple values.

```
SELECT contractid
    ,milestoneid
    ,DATE
    ,type
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY contractid ORDER BY Milestoneid ASC) AS RankNbr
FROM [TSWDATA].[dbo].t_milestone
WHERE contractid = 1056229


contractid milestoneid  date        type               RankNbr
1056        43269       10/10/15    Full                1
1056        43449       10/26/15    GB                  2
1056        43456       10/26/15    Submit for Funding  3
1056        43463       10/26/15    Cleared             4
```

I need to join to the main contract table and pull the contract only when the value 'GB' is the maximum milestoneid.

Can I do this in the where clause?

Comment: (I removed the mysql tag, as this is clearly applicable to MS SQL Server only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the records from your contracts table, then you can join to your ranked query.  Just change your order by to DESC so the RankNbr 1 will be the maximum milestoneid

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TSWDATA].[dbo].t_contract c
JOIN (
    SELECT contractid
        ,type
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY contractid ORDER BY Milestoneid DESC) AS RankNbr
    FROM [TSWDATA].[dbo].t_milestone
) ms ON ms.contractid = c.contractid
WHERE 
    --contractid = 1056229 AND 
    ms.RankNbr = 1 AND ms.type = 'GB'
```

Comment: JamieD77 - this works perfectly.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
 SELECT contractid
      ,milestoneid
     ,DATE
     ,type
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY contractid ORDER BY Milestoneid ASC) AS    RankNbr
 FROM [TSWDATA].[dbo].t_milestone
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) *
               FROM SubTable AS s
               WHERE s.type = 'GB'
                 AND s.contractID = [TSWDATA].[dbo].t_milestone.contractid
               ORDER BY s.milestoneID DESC
              )
   AND contractid = 1056229
```